# Rails: before_save - Stack level too deep

Tags: ruby-on-rails, before-save, stack-level

I have this simple model:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord

    after_create_commit :process
    before_save :re_process, on: :update

    has_one :processed, class_name: 'Post::Process'

    def process
        self.processed.destroy if self.processed
        processed = self.build_processed
        processed.save!
    end

    private

    def re_process
        self.process if self.title_changed?
    end

end
```

I get a `Stack level to deep` error everytime I create a new `Post`.

Now when I remove `before_save :re_process, on: :update` everything works fine.

Shouldn't this line take only affect when I am updating a post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`on: :update or on: :create` doesn't work for `before_save`

For this purpose, you have to use `before_update`

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord

    after_create_commit :process
    before_update :re_process

    has_one :processed, class_name: 'Post::Process'

    def process
        self.processed.destroy if self.processed
        processed = self.build_processed
        processed.save!
    end

    private

    def re_process
        self.process if self.title_changed?
    end

end
```

If you are using `on` option with `before_save`, the callback will be executed no matter what is specified in `on` option.

Hope this helps

Comment: Works, thank you! That's what I was trying to accomplish :)

Comment: Glad to help you

Answer (score 8):

Yes, the before_save you added on `update` it's working fine.

The problem is that you have the `after_create_commit` which the code saves the record after it was already created.

```
def process
  # here the Post was already created
  self.processed.destroy if self.processed
  processed = self.build_processed
  processed.save! # And here, you are updating the Post, so it triggers the re_process
end
```

So, basically, when you create a Post:

1. Saves the Post
2. Calls `process` callback (after_create_commit)
3. Calls `re_process` (because it's called in `process` method when
   doing `save!`)
4. Calls `process` again (because it's called in `re_process`)
5. And so on...

This loop is causing the `Stack level to deep`

Hope it helped!

Comment: 3. step: Why on earth does saving `processed` lead to trigger `before_save` for `self` (a post)?

Comment: Shouldn't `before_save` only get triggered by `self.save!`?

Comment: @ariel `on: :update or on: :create` does'nt work on before_save

For this purpose, you have to use before_update